# converting an array of objects to a different structure of array of objects

Tags: javascript, dataset

how do i turn this:

```
var colors = ["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e","#2ca02c", "#d62728"];

file = 
[ 
{ 
DeviceName: 'DeviceName1',
counter1: '85%',
counter2: '87%',
counter3: '75%',
counter4: '63%' },
{ 
DeviceName: 'DeviceName2',
counter1: '85%',
counter2: '87%',
counter3: '75%',
counter4: '63%' 
} 
]
```

in to this:

```
data = [
      {
        key: "counter1",
        color: "#1f77b4",
        values:
          [      
            { x : "DeviceName1", y : '85%' },
            { x : "DeviceName2", y : '87%' }
          ]
      },
      {
        key: "counter2",
        color: "#ff7f0e",
        values:
          [      
            { x : "DeviceName1", y : '85%' },
            { x : "DeviceName2", y : '87%' }
          ]
      },
      {
        key: "counter3",
        color: "#2ca02c",
        values:
          [      
            { x : "DeviceName1", y : '85%' },
            { x : "DeviceName2", y : '87%' }
          ]
      },
      {
        key: "counter4",
        color: "#d62728",
        values:
          [      
            { x : "DeviceName1", y : '85%' },
            { x : "DeviceName2", y : '87%' }
          ]
      }
    ];
```

So i basically want 1 counter in each object of the array

this is me getting started, a long way of yet, but I wondering how or whether to use map or reduce to achieve this.

```
file.map(function(item,i){
    return { key: item

        }
    })
```

Comment: Keep going with map(). What is your specific question? it sounds like you are expecting someone to code this for you

Answer (score 0):

This code is very arbitrary but if you want that specific conversion this would do it for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/na2ysko2/

```
var data = [];
Object.keys(file[0])
  .filter(function(k){ return k !== 'DeviceName' })
  .forEach(function(key,i) {
    data.push({
      key: key,
      color: colors[i],
      values: file.map(function(d) {
        return {
          x: d.DeviceName,
          y: d[key]
        }
      })
    });
  });
```

This makes a lot of assumptions that the data is consistently in the format you specified.